# In which issue of 2000AD did King Rudraige mac Dela appear?

Tags: 2000ad

The Wikipedia page for Sláine (2000AD) mentions King Rudraige mac Dela:

> King Rudraige mac Dela – Ruler of the city of Gorlias and guardian of the 
>   Silver Sword of the Moon. His hand was bitten off by Avagddu and replaced
>   with a metal prosthesis, preventing him from becoming High King. He was 
>   married to Niamh for a year but left her for a warrior resembling Arnold 
>   Schwarzenegger's Conan.

In which Sláine story did this happen? (With 2000AD prog no. if possible!)

Comment: You'd have to look at the individual progs to find all the story bits listed above. They didn't happen in a single issue, but were described over several issues if I recall correctly...

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was about as comprehensive as you're going to get. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 1):

According to comicbookdb.com, the character of [Rudraige](http://comicbookdb.com/character.php?ID=45035) appeared (or was mentioned) in 8 separate editions, covering the story arc "Slaine: The Horned God";

The relevant progs are 633, 634, 635, 663, 691, 692, 697 and 698.